# Does c++ have a "private protected" accessor like c#?

Tags: c#, c++

C# has a `private protected` accessor:

> "The `private protected` keyword combination is a member access
> modifier. A `private protected` member is accessible by types derived
> from the containing class, but only within its containing assembly."

(From: [private protected (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected)).

This seems useful for class libraries, yet I couldn't find if there was
something similar I could use in c++. Is there such a thing, and if not, is there an architectural reason or is it simply not a thing?

Comment: C++ doesn't have a "containing assembly", so no.

Comment: The C++ toolchain has a linker.  That's a problem, compiled source can end up in any module, as determined by the linker.  So at compile-time it is quite difficult to guarantee adherence to module scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not have the notion of an assembly or any other entity similar to a .NET assembly.

Libraries as a general mechanism for packing various software components are also not a term that appears in the C++ standard (it is indeed a common mechanism supplied by the most if not all implementations but it is not required by the standard).

Therefore there's no meaning to a qualifier of that sort in C++.

The closest thing that you can achieve is with C++ [modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) - introduced in C++20. You can have e.g. a class which is not exported and therefore visible only within the module.